# how to get rid of duplicates based on the second column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019],
    'date': ['01.01.2017', '22.04.2018', '31.01.2018', '19.03.2019', '03.12.2019'],
    'id': ['72297143', '6de190ee', '0e1e8e89', 'ab4f99ab', '7d81a711']
})
```

For each dublicated value in `year` column (like 2019 and 2019), I want to keep the one that has the latest `date` (in the above example it's 03.12.2019).

In the end I want to drop `date` column and only keep `year` and `id`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `sort_values` using `drop_duplicated`

```
df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date,dayfirst=True)
yourdf=df.sort_values('date').drop_duplicates('year',keep='last')
yourdf
Out[413]: 
   year       date        id
0  2017 2017-01-01  72297143
1  2018 2018-04-22  6de190ee
4  2019 2019-12-03  7d81a711
yourdf.drop('id',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### sort then ...

Very similar to [@WeNYoBen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56228157/2336654).  Difference being that I maintain the existing `date` whatever it is and sort by the converted values.

```
df.iloc[pd.to_datetime(df.date, dayfirst=True).argsort()] \
  .drop_duplicates('year', keep='last')

   year        date        id
0  2017  01.01.2017  72297143
1  2018  22.04.2018  6de190ee
4  2019  03.12.2019  7d81a711
```

---

#### `groupby` and `idxmax`

Again, I'm preserving whatever the original datatype is in `date`.  If you want actual datetimes, it is trivial to assign the results to the dataframe.

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df.date, dayfirst=True).groupby(df.year).idxmax()]

   year        date        id
0  2017  01.01.2017  72297143
1  2018  22.04.2018  6de190ee
4  2019  03.12.2019  7d81a711
```